# R knit to html: Image cannot show

Tags: r, linux, archlinux

I use an example of R markdown:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

I can run all code chunks without error, a plot is ok.
I click "knit to html" to make html, everything is good.
But when I open html file in browser, a image of plot does not show.

[plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTtIh.png)

Image also does not show when I using `include_graphics` function.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, I tried you code, but everything is fine for me. You are using which browser?

Comment: @EmmanuelHamel Chrome, Firefox are the same. I have run it on Windows and the same result. So I think the problem is in R and ArchLinux.

Comment: I ran it on Windows and it works on my end.